# Is it possible to add templating or loop to terraform module

Tags: terraform

If I have a terraform module:

```
module "name_1" {
  source = "../some_path"
  account_id = "name_1"
}

module "name_2" {
  source = "../some_path"
  account_id = "name_2"
}

module "name_3" {
  source = "../some_path"
  account_id = "name_3"
}
```

Is it possible to add some logic (loop) or templating so that I do not have to repeat module again and again

Something like:

```
module "name_{num}" {
  source = "../some_path"
  account_id = "name_{num}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now (Terraform 0.11), this is not possible. The upcoming version 0.12 will bring a lot of improvements due to a better HCL parser.

As described [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each), there is the plan for the following syntax, which **will not yet be available with 0.12**:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = var.subnet_numbers

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.example.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.example.cidr_block, 8, each.value)
}
```

Nevertheless, I guess we're all looking forward to that..

Comment: Note that 0.11, normal resources like `aws_subnet` _can_ be scaled using `count` ([doku](https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/count.html)). However, this is not possible with `modules`.